# Save variable as variable in MYSQL for later use

Tags: php, mysql

I have an email template which i am saving in database. My problem is some part of message are variable means these data are coming from current user data.
For Example My Template is

```
$message="This is test for $username. I am sending mail to $email."
```

here `$username` and `$email` is coming from current users and it is varying from user to user.
So problem is how to save it in database so i can use it as variable on php page later.
anybody have any idea please help me.your help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to save?  The string with the placeholders or the resulting string after it's been populated with values?  Either way, you'd write it to the database as any other string value.

Comment: instead of $ you can switch to { for example {username}, then you can use str_replace in future for any substitution of variable

Comment: i want to save string with placeholders.

Comment: @Pundit has a good example, but this can be done the way you are doing it with eval. For example, if you want to print the string containing $username and you want the variable value of $username to replace the variable name in the string, you use: eval("print \"$yourstring\";"); But (and this is a huge BUT), you should never use eval with user-supplied data. That is why I like Pundit's solution as it doesn't eval possible malicious code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to store whole template in database, you can save it using your own created constants e.g. [USERNAME], [EMAIL] and then in php script just use *str_replace()* on them.

```
$messageTemplate = 'This is test for [USERNAME]. I am sending mail to [EMAIL].';
$message = str_replace(array('[USERNAME]', '[EMAIL]'), array($username, $email), $messageTemplate);
```

But you can also divide this string and concatenate it with variables from database as follows:

```
$message = 'This is test for ' . $username . '. I am sending mail to ' . $email . '.';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
$input = "This is test for {username}. I am sending mail to {email}.";

$tokens = array("username" => $username, "email" => $email);

$tmp = $input;
foreach($tokens as $key => $token)
{
    $tmp = str_replace("{".$key."}", $token, $tmp);
}
echo $tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables in the string will not be evaluated as variables automatically just because you are adding it to your php scope. You need to eval the string in order for the variables to be replaced:

```
$username = 'test';
$email = 'test@test.com';
$str = "This is a test for $username. I am sending mail to some person $email.";

echo $str. "\n";
// This is a test for $username. I am sending mail to some person $email.
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
// This is a test for test. I am sending mail to some person test@test.com.
```

For more information, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Variables set inside single quotes will not be interpolated unless concatenated. `$str = 'This is test for $username. I am sending mail to $email.';` will fail. `$str = "This is test for $username. I am sending mail to $email.";`

Comment: and please note while using eval, that someone could inject bad code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks fred, btw, could you tell how come the example used single quotes if that wouldn't work? i'm curious.

Comment: You're welcome. As previously noted, using `eval()` has security-related issues and should be used with the utmost of care. Raphael made a point about that, therefore and in the OP's case, `eval()` is not needed to use. A simple replacement of single quotes to doubles and removing `eval()` will be much safer to use.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  you got everyone confused. Vinie, this only seems to work, but it doesn't serve the purpose you need. The interpolation takes place at the first definition of the string (in your case this would be before inserting into the db) not at the eval (in your case after getting the template from db), the first definition of the string should not have double quotes. http://ideone.com/K30Fjg - both printed strings contain the interpolated variables - first print should not contain the interpolated variables - like this: http://ideone.com/vh8Dkk (which is the initial proposed solution)

Comment: @Sorin Yeah I know, I realized that afterwards. However the use of `eval()` should be avoided and wasn't needed in OP's case. A simple echo with double quotes encapsulation would have sufficed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You don't seem to get the question. The string needs to be eval-ed, PHP doesn't do interpolation of strings extracted from the DB, or other external sources. See: http://ideone.com/xtB73s (I use stdin instead of the db, to ilustrate a point)

Comment: @Sorin No arguement there. PHP may not, however SQL will, that I know for a fact, I use it myself. Therefore, an alternate solution could have been provided. I made a mistake, we all do from time to time; nobody's perfect and I stand at making another mistake somewhere down the road. If someone doesn't make a mistake somewhere, that person would not have learned anything ;) Thanks for the information, I have "learned" something today. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- , it's not the first time you take things way to personally. I don't really care about your mistakes, I just want that future users can understand and reuse the answers. As for the "SQL interpolating variables" I really doubt that, but I don't intend to waste my time discussing that.

Comment: @Sorin I don't keep track of a person's (past) behaviour nor have I ever made a mention to anyone else about theirs. I made a mistake, plain and simple. Let's just say I've learned from my past mistakes. I don't live in the past. I don't want to keep discussing it neither, so let's just leave it at that.